# Getting 'Error writing to file' during WiX Toolset upgrade when changing installation scope

Tags: wix, wix4

I recently upgraded my application's installer created with WiX Toolset 4. In the older version, I did not specify a scope, while in the newer version, I set the scope to "perUser" to allow Non-Admin users to install the app aswell.

However, when attempting to update the application from the old version to the new one using the new installer, I encounter errors like

> "Error writing to file filename.exe. Verify that you have access to
> the directory."

Both the old and new setups are installed in the same folder within **AppData**. Additionally, I use the `<MajorUpgrade>` element in my setup to ensure that the previous version is uninstalled before installing the new one. Despite this, I'm still facing this issue.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Logs** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZrghUpY-6AsooCDKDY-bUp1CiVHdL3Z2/view?usp=sharing